# Night mode: Disable in certain apps

Tags: oneplus-5t

I just got a new OnePlus 5T. (Upgraded from a Nexus 5X.) I like the new Night Mode, as it does natively what I used the Twillight app for in my previous phone. But, I don't know how to make it automatically stop in certain apps. For example, when I'm watching a movie in the evening, I don't want to have its colors be yellow. Is that possible?